# How to stop variable being reset every time the class is called?

Tags: logic, discord.py

Sorry the title wasn't very clear. Anyway, So basically I'm making a discord bot that saves every message and compares the messages together to find out if it's spam. Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("-"*16)

    game = discord.Game("Discord")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

# Spam Stopper
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    message1 = message
    spam_num = 1
    
    if spam_num == 1 and message == message1:
        message2 = message
        spam_num += 1

    elif spam_num == 2 and message == message1 and message == message2:
        message3 = message
        spam_num += 1
    
    elif spam_num >= 3 and message == message1 and message == message2 and message == message3:
        message.delete()
    
    else:
        spam_num = 0

client.run('token here')
```

Now, the problem is is that I can't set the variable outside of this function because I get an error saying the variable is outside the local loop. So, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [Variable Scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp). To solve your problem, you should put your variables in the global scope, instead of the local scope, and when you want to reuse them, globalize your local variables, so you can use it to compare the next message.

Comment: I just tried doing that, but now it doesn't work and there's no error. I moved the spam_num to here `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

spam_num=0`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to globalize your local variables

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I haven't coded python in a while.

Comment: Read the link I provided. Use the ‘global var’ at the top of your function.